# Converting `numpy.str_` with a number and parenthesis, to a integer

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I've been reading some similar questions about this, but none of them was specific.

I have a variable

`a = '[ 4.777]'` which is a `numpy.str_`

I would like to change its type to `a = 4.777` where `type(a) = int`. How do I do that?

I tried writing `a = np.array(a, dtype='|S4')` but it didn't work.

Comment: where does the data come from?

Comment: A simulation, but it's not important.

Comment: It is. Why does the simulation return a string, and not a list of floats or a float array?

Comment: because I have to write it down somewhere else before creating the table

Comment: then write down a float?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json.loads()`:

```
import json
b = json.loads(a)[0]
print type(b)
```

And type of `a` is `<type 'numpy.string_'>`

When `a = '[ 4.777]'`, the output will be:

```
float
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression with `re` to extract `float` from text:

```
import re

a = '[ 4.777]'
a = re.findall('[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+', a)[0]
```

Now `a` will be of type `str` but you can convert it to desired type.